# QTreeView policy subclass. Is this sane?

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I am kinda sick of making subclasses for each minor modification I need to make in QWhateverView behaviour so I got an idea:

What if I make a ProxyView for most commonly overriden functions that will essentially do stuff like:

```
//(mousePress used as an example)
void ProxyView::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event ) 
{
    if(mousePressFunctionHandler != nullptr)
       functionHandler(this, event);
    else
       QTreeView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

While it's true that I won't have access to view's internals this way, I often don't need it anyway... The only thing stopping me so far is that I am not sure if this idea is sane or not... :)

Or is there better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to use [event filters](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).

Comment: You are, indeed, correct... My head was clouded it seems :)  I considered it then discarded idea for reason I cannot remember now reevaluated and this is exactly what I need.